# Docker Stack Deploy Can't Visit The Port Of Mapping

Tags: windows, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, devops

I'm ready to deploy my website in windows docker container,
In this script : [ **docker-compose up** ] , everything is fine, I can reach my web;

```html
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: haltan1118/aspdotnetcore:1.0.0
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 250M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8111:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
 webnet:



 docker-compose up
```

[compose_script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou3qp.png)

[good_website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtoMk.png)

but if I build it with script [**Docker Stack Deploy**],
docker shows website's running status is ok, every point is running, but I can't reach them !
And system has no logs to check this problem.

```
  docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mywebtest
```

[stack_deploy_status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGXSW.png)

[bad_website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftaAd.png)

Comment: Does anybody has this stuff as me ?

Comment: Please update your question including all the source code as text and not inside an image.

Comment: @ luis.parravicini The configs and scripts are easy to copy, but the result I can't print it ,let it stay in picture ok?

Comment: change `haltan1118/aspdotnetcore:1.0.0` to `nginx:latest` if you can access the web then the problem is with `haltan1118/aspdotnetcore:1.0.0` image.

Comment: @Kishore Kadiyala OMG , this is the key ！the image has something wrong, thx alot !